# NSLayoutConstraint and assigning a variable that is an int

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I feel this might be a very simple question as I'm just getting started with Swift but am a bit confused about this behavior.

I have an NSLayoutConstraint that looks like this:

```
let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, 
         attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
        toItem: view, 
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 
        multiplier: 1, 
        constant: 0)
```

and works fine. When I change it to

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  let newView = UIView()
  var verticalStartingPoint = 0

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    newView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    view.addSubview(newView)

    // not the part that is problem
    let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, 
         attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 
         relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
         toItem: view, 
         attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 
         multiplier: 1, 
         constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)


    var verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, 
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 
       relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
      toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 
      multiplier: 1, 
      constant: self.verticalStartingPoint  // <- seems to be error
)
view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)
```

It gives me an error stating:

> /Users/jt/tmp-ios/autolayout-test/autolayout-test/ViewController.swift:31:30:
>   Cannot find an initializer for type 'NSLayoutConstraint' that accepts
>   an argument list of type '(item: UIView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute,
>   relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation, toItem: UIView!, attribute:
>   NSLayoutAttribute, multiplier: Int, constant: Int)'

But I'm not sure why? It seems like I'm just assinging a variable in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift won't automatically convert a variable of type `Int` to a variable of type `CGFloat`. You have to convert explicitly:

```
var verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView,
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
    toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY,
    multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(self.verticalStartingPoint))
```

Swift will automatically convert a numeric integer literal (like “`0`”) to any numeric type. That's why your first try worked.

Instead of converting in the call to `NSLayoutConstraint`, you could change the variable's type instead:

```
var verticalStartingPoint: CGFloat = 0
```